# How to make an Azure Image public?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services, amazon-ami

I have an Azure Image that I created using Packer. Now, I want to reference this image in an Azure Resource Management template that I want to open source. So, for anyone to use my ARM template, that Azure Image has to be public. How can I accomplish this?

I'm a big AWS user, so what I'm essentially trying to do is create an AMI and set it's permissions to "public" so anyone can use, but in Azure.

Comment: Upload to Azure Blob storage and set the access type on the container to `blob` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources#set-container-permissions-in-the-azure-portal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with evilSnobu, you can upload your VHD to Azure blob storage account, and set the access type to Blob(**anonymous read access for blob only**). You can use the **URL** in template to deploy Azure VM.
[image]

Also you can upload VHD to Azure storage account and use **SAS** (shared access signatures) to that blob.

More information about SAS, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

About use Azure PowerShell to create SAS, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestorageblobsastoken?view=azurermps-5.4.0).

Comment: Thanks for the information! So I need to stop creating Managed Images in Packer and instead create VHDs?

Comment: @gkrizek No, you can use packer to create image, then you can use that image to create new VM, then generate that VM, then share that VHD.

Comment: But if Packer supports creating a VHD from the start, wouldn't that be easier?   -    https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure.html#vhd-or-managed-image

Comment: Yes, because Azure image will not share to public, so you should create VHD and share this VHD.

Comment: I'm learning about leases on VHDs and this seems like a problem. I'm wanting this to act like an AMI, so virtually unlimited VMs can be created from one image. With VHDs it seems like it treats it as an actual drive and can only be mounted to 1 VM. Can you direct me in the correct way of doing this?